Signature verification failed. Missing signature for public key(s) [key1, key2] in jest test using anchor
test :
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { RoyaltyNft } from "../target/types/royalty_nft";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/token";
import { getAssociatedTokenAddressSync } from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("royalty nft", () => {
    const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
    const connectiobn = provider.connection;
    const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
    anchor.setProvider(provider);

    const program = anchor.workspace.RoyaltyNft as Program<RoyaltyNft>;

    it("initiate contract", async () => {
        await program.methods
            .intializeContract()
            .accounts({
                payer: wallet.publicKey,
            })
            .signers([wallet.payer])
            .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });
    });

    it("create nft", async () => {
        const [contractStatePda, contractStateBump] =
            await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [Buffer.from("deauthe")],
                program.programId
            );

        const [royaltyPoolAccount, royaltyPoolBump] =
            await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [Buffer.from("royalty_pool")],
                program.programId
            );
        const [mintPda, mintPdaBump] =
            await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [Buffer.from("mint")],
                program.programId
            );

        const [tokenAccountPda, tokenAccountBump] =
            await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
                [
                    wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
                    program.programId.toBuffer(),
                    mintPda.toBuffer(),
                ],
                anchor.utils.token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            );

        const tx = await program.methods
            .createNft("SYM", "NAME", "https://google.com")
            .accountsPartial({
                contractState: contractStatePda,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                payer: wallet.publicKey,
                royaltyPoolAccount,
            })

            .signers([wallet.payer])
            .rpc({ skipPreflight: true });

        console.log("create nft transaction", tx);

        await anchor.getProvider().connection.confirmTransaction(tx, "processed");
        expect(tx).toBeDefined();
    });

    console.log("done");
});


contract :
use crate::state::{ContractState, RoyaltyPool};
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token;
use anchor_spl::token::{InitializeMint, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount};
use mpl_token_metadata::instructions::{
    CreateMasterEditionV3Cpi, CreateMasterEditionV3InstructionArgs, CreateMetadataAccountV3Cpi,
    CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs,
};
use mpl_token_metadata::programs::MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_ID;
use mpl_token_metadata::types::Creator;
use mpl_token_metadata::types::DataV2;

pub fn create_nft(
    ctx: Context<CreateNft>,
    name: String,
    symbol: String,
    uri: String,
) -> Result<()> {
    let payer = &ctx.accounts.payer;
    let rent = &ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info();

    let creators = vec![Creator {
        address: ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
        verified: true,
        share: 100, // Full ownership to the payer
    }];

    // 1. Initialize the mint account for the NFT (1 decimal, fixed supply of 1)
    token::initialize_mint(
        ctx.accounts.initialize_mint_ctx(),
        0, // Decimals: NFTs have 0 decimals
        &payer.key(),
        Some(&payer.key()),
    )?;

    // 2. Create metadata for the NFT
    let mint_key = &ctx.accounts.mint.key();
    let metadata_seeds = &[
        b"metadata",
        mpl_token_metadata::ID.as_ref(),
        &mint_key.to_bytes(),
    ];
    let (metadata_pda, _) = Pubkey::find_program_address(metadata_seeds, &mpl_token_metadata::ID);
    msg!("metadata pda : {}", metadata_pda);

    let metadata_account_cpi: CreateMetadataAccountV3Cpi<'_, '_> = CreateMetadataAccountV3Cpi {
        __program: &ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        __args: CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionArgs {
            collection_details: None,
            data: DataV2 {
                collection: None,
                creators: Some(creators),
                name,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 500,
                symbol,
                uri,
                uses: None,
            },
            is_mutable: false,
        },
        metadata: &ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        mint: &ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        mint_authority: &payer,
        payer: &payer,
        rent: Some(rent),
        system_program: &ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        update_authority: (&payer.to_account_info(), false),
    };
    let metadata_account_result = metadata_account_cpi.invoke();
    match metadata_account_result {
        Ok(_) => msg!("metadata account creation succesfull"),
        Err(e) => msg!(",etadata account creation failedx with err : {}", e),
    }

    //3. mint the nft to the user's account
    let mint_to_res = token::mint_to(ctx.accounts.mint_to_ctx(), 1);
    match mint_to_res {
        Ok(_) => msg!("minting to account succesful"),
        Err(e) => msg!("minting to account failed with error : {}", e),
    }

    //4. create master edition account

    let master_edition = CreateMasterEditionV3Cpi {
        __program: &ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
        __args: CreateMasterEditionV3InstructionArgs {
            max_supply: Some(1),
        },
        edition: &ctx.accounts.edition_account.to_account_info(),
        metadata: &ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        mint: &ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        mint_authority: &ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        payer: &ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        rent: Some(rent),
        system_program: &ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        token_program: &ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        update_authority: &ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
    };
    let master_edition_res = master_edition.invoke();
    match master_edition_res {
        Ok(_) => msg!("master edition creation s'uccesfull"),
        Err(e) => msg!("master edition account creation failed with error : {}", e),
    }

    //5. update contract state
    let contract_state = &mut ctx.accounts.contract_state;
    contract_state.add_item();

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateNft<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    ///CHECK : this is safe because we dont read or write from this account
    #[account(
    init,
    payer = payer,
    mint::decimals = 0,
    mint::authority = payer,
    mint::freeze_authority = payer,
)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>, //space is not required when creating spl accounts

    ///CHECK : this is safe because we dont read or write from this account
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        seeds = [b"metadata", mpl_token_metadata::ID.as_ref(), mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 256
    )]
    pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>, //check if a struct has to be created for this

    ///CHECK : this is safe because we dont read or write from this account
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        seeds = [b"metadata", mpl_token_metadata::ID.as_ref(), mint.key().as_ref(), b"edition"],
        bump,
        space = 82
    )]
    pub edition_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    ///CHECK : this is safe because we dont read or write from this account
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = payer,
    )]
    pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    ///CHECK : this is safe because we dont read or write from this account
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        seeds = [RoyaltyPool::SEED_PREFIX, mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + RoyaltyPool::INIT_SPACE,
    )]
    pub royalty_pool_account: Account<'info, RoyaltyPool>,

    #[account(mut, seeds = [ContractState::SEED_PREFIX.as_ref()], bump)]
    pub contract_state: Account<'info, ContractState>,

    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    ///CHECK : this is safe because we dont read or write from this account
    #[account(address = MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_ID)]
    pub token_metadata_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

impl<'info> CreateNft<'info> {
    fn initialize_mint_ctx(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, InitializeMint<'info>> {
        //this account below might have to be changed later
        let _signer : &[&[&[u8]]];

        CpiContext::new( //should I use new_with_signer here?
            self.token_program.to_account_info(),
            InitializeMint {
                mint: self.mint.to_account_info(),
                rent: self.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
        )
    }

    fn mint_to_ctx(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, MintTo<'info>> {
        CpiContext::new(
            self.token_program.to_account_info(),
            MintTo {
                mint: self.mint.to_account_info(),
                to: self.token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: self.payer.to_account_info(),
            },
        )
    }
}


error I'm getting on running the test with anchor test
 FAIL  tests/bankrun.spec.ts
  ● Console

    console.log
      tx 2Zq51XfWYyb2zj9Lh32nXKnT4P6ggvxui7EwtbjNKgkJcHePRREAU1duWNe6Hom3H3vznT7Mjzci8JzwokUMm35V

      at tests/bankrun.spec.ts:45:12

    console.log
      payer account : 9xj9My2tSvNFaXzQupz8piedQMPpGFF9XEMU6ZnguKYE

      at tests/bankrun.spec.ts:46:12

    console.log
      tx 3U35BnF2mp3iQBX4uTqdmcgUM1fr1etSGfkhUaPViZQHhM8eQTG5jFZk68k1F4mDgx6T7mYYGF2h9Zf5Bj5igQvZ

      at tests/bankrun.spec.ts:73:12

    console.log
      payer account : 9xj9My2tSvNFaXzQupz8piedQMPpGFF9XEMU6ZnguKYE

      at tests/bankrun.spec.ts:74:12

    console.log
      mintPda DVbVoYZ3G6VhoQHwnTKknDbgqQLE3vYcCG4agDQgNAhC

      at tests/bankrun.spec.ts:103:11

    console.log
      tokenAccountPda 2ePd58uHhfDFMHG7PLH1pdedBXQ49i2HJvuEbxQVqoaz

      at tests/bankrun.spec.ts:104:11

  ● royalty_nft › create_nft

    Signature verification failed.
    Missing signature for public key(s) [`2ePd58uHhfDFMHG7PLH1pdedBXQ49i2HJvuEbxQVqoaz`, `DVbVoYZ3G6VhoQHwnTKknDbgqQLE3vYcCG4agDQgNAhC`].

      at Transaction.serialize (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction/legacy.ts:828:15)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:160:22)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)

The missing signatures appear to be the tokenAccountPda and the mintPda from the test logs.
Since these are Pdas and I wish to use the program.methods... calls to call the transactions, what is exactly going wrong here?

I got the same issue
